# googlemap marker with refresh button

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new to android development and I want to use google map with refresh button.  When refresh will be press first time marker disappears, second time again marker come, third time again disappears, fourth time marker come and so on.

How  to refresh data and marker on google map ,when I am trying it gets marker after double click.

Comment: You should add some code. See how to ask. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what have you done till now ? please do add some code of your work. it will be easy to suggest a solution according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a marker from the map, call the `setMap()` method passing null as the argument.

```
marker.setMap(null);
```

The above method does not delete the marker. It simply removes the marker from the map.

To display again the markers on the map you can call again the `setMap()` method.

Check this [code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove) on how to use it.

NOTE: Ignore the delete marker part. And Combine the two onclick action in one button(refresh button).